# Why I can't get the correct output when moving data from text file to array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I am getting weird output when I try to move information from textfile to array, anyone can help me to figure the problem? Much appreciate for that.

Information in textfile
[image: Information in textfile]

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream indata;
    string name[10] , id[10] , gender[10];
    int i = 0 , age[10];
    double weight[10] , height[10];
    indata.open("Staff.txt");   

    while(!indata.eof())
    {
        if(indata.eof()==true)
           break;
        else
        {
           getline(indata,name[i]);
           indata >> id[i] >> gender[i] >> age[i] >> weight[i] >> height[i];
           cout << name[i] <<" "<< id[i] <<" "<< gender[i] <<" "<< age[i] <<" "<< weight[i] <<" "<< 
           height[i] <<endl;
           i++;
        }       
     }
     system("pause");
     return 0;
   }
```

Here is the output
[image: Here is the output]

Comment: All pertinent information must be included ***in the question itself as plain text***. Dodgy links to suspicious external web sites can stop working at any time, making the question useless, and images cannot be read by people with reading disabilities. You need to [edit] your question and replace images with plain text. For more information, see [ask] questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last formatted extraction of the iteration (`indata >> height[i]`) leaves the newline character in the buffer, so when the next iteration runs the `std::getline` will see that character, extract it and stop reading further characters. This messes up further input operations leading the output you see.

A quick fix would be to remove any leading whitespace before running `std::getline`. You also are incorrectly using the `eof()` method. Good practice is to run the input operation first and *then* check if it succeeded with `fail()`.

So this is what it should look like:

```
while (std::getline(indata >> std::ws, name[i]) &&
       indata >> id[i] >> gender[i] >> age[i] >> weight[i] >> height[i]) {
  // ...
}
```

`indata >> std::ws` removes leading whitespace and putting the input operation in the condition of the while loop will invoke the inner boolean operator which calls `fail()`.

Comment: I try to use std::ws that you have mentioned but i get error of 'std::ws' does not have class type. Can I know what is the error about? Thank you for you answer

Comment: Ok i already know how to solve it. I have to add <sstream> as library for std::ws to function. Thank you very much for your help.